# How to Reset OpenVPN password in ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: 16.04

Can anyone help me on how to reset the **openVPN** authentication password?

Like the **forget password** feature in windows OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you have forgotten the password for this user on your OpenVPN Access Server you can reset the password for the "openvpn" user on the command line with :

```
passwd openvpn
```

**Please note that you can not and should not use the "root" user credentials to login at the Admin UI.**

[Source from openvpn.net](https://docs.openvpn.net/configuration/)

Comment: the specific command is not working in the terminal... Showing error as ¨passwd: user 'openvpn' does not exist¨

Comment: what is the output when you try it?